Metagen function of R meta package not showing weights when using subgroups
Working with this data:

I have no trouble plotting the forest tree with weight information:
meta_result_ifi_any_or_ctc <- metagen(
    TE = log(mv_ifi_any_or_ctc$variable_multi_measure),
    lower = log(mv_ifi_any_or_ctc$variable_multi_95neg),
    upper = log(mv_ifi_any_or_ctc$variable_multi_95pos),
    studlab = paste(mv_ifi_any_or_ctc$first_author, "&", mv_ifi_any_or_ctc$last_author, mv_ifi_any_or_ctc$year_publication),
    sm = "OR",
    fixed = FALSE,
    random = TRUE,
    overall = TRUE,
    layout = "revman"
  )
 
  forest(meta_result_ifi_any_or_ctc)


But when trying to do the same using subgroups, like this:
meta_result <- metagen(
    TE = log(data$variable_multi_measure),
    lower = log(data$variable_multi_95neg),
    upper = log(data$variable_multi_95pos),
    studlab = paste(data$first_author, "&", data$last_author, data$year_publication),
    sm = "OR",
    subgroup = data$variable_name,
    data = data,
    study.weight = TRUE,
    weight.subgroup = data$variable_name,
    print.subgroup.weight = TRUE,
    fixed = FALSE,
    random = TRUE,
    overall = FALSE,
    layout = "revman"
  )

    forest(meta_result, 
           rightlabs = c("OR", "95% CI", "Weight"),
           comb.random = TRUE,
           showweights = TRUE)


Then the weights dont show:

Any ideas?
